# Dual monitor setup on Windows 10 with nvidia pci card requires reboot to enable second display

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia

- Mainboard: GA-MA78LMT-US2H (Gigabyte Technology)
- CPU: AMD Athlon II X4 640
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 (latest updates installed)
- OS: Windows 10 (22H2, latest updates installed)

Two monitors are attached, primary via DVI, secondary via VGA. In BIOS I changed the default graphic card from onboard to PCI (so there is no onboard graphic card anymore in the device manager).
After a cold boot the OS only activates the primary display, the secondary is not available. In this situation, the NVIDIA GUI shows a "analog display" which I can't enable (checkbox unchecked).
Only a soft reboot enables the second display. This seems reproducible, so shutting the PC down, then cold boot it again there's only one monitor active, a reboot fixes it every time (apparently). It's not my own PC so my access is quite limited, responses could take some time. This was not an issue with the onboard graphics only.

What I've tried so far:

- Activate the onboard graphics
- Update all components (Windows, graphics drivers)
- Search the system logs
  What I plan to do next:
- Boot a Linux live system from USB to see if that problem persists across distros
- Look for a NVIDIA BIOS to see if there are more options to test
- Replace mainboard battery

Until then I'd appreciate any comments, I can't seem to wrap my head around it. For full disclosure, I'm not very experienced with graphic cards, I' more of a laptop person, so bear with me.

Update: Using an openSUSE live image via USB I could not reproduce this issue. Each cold start resulted in two active monitors right away. I assume that this is some sort of driver issue, isn't it? What else could I check?